# Using sed output in another script or command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, arguments, output

How can I use the output of `sed` in another script?

For example (this doesn't work):

```
sed -n "$COUNTER",1p /domains.csv | wget
```

or

```
sed -n "$COUNTER",1p /domains.csv > /myScript.sh
```

As far as I know `>` lets me take the output and put it in a file, I'm just unsure of how to use this output as an argument in another script.

(I am aware I can declare the output as a variable, and then use it on the next line. I'm interested in how to do this as one "command")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `|` takes output and redirects it into stdin. `wget` needs a command line argument, not stdin so you want to pipe to `xargs` which will build a command line from stdin.

```
sed -n "$COUNTER",1p /domains.csv | xargs wget
```

Alternatively you can tell wget to take input on stdin

```
sed -n "$COUNTER",1p /domains.csv | wget -i -
```

Comment: Aha!! thanks so much, that'll do it. Thanks also for the explanation